# SparkR - cast to date format

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

How do I cast string to date with a specific format for a Spark dataframe?

In dplyr, I would do this:

```
df = data.frame(dt1 = c("22DEC16", "12JUN16"), x = c(10,20))
df = df %>% mutate(dt2 = as.Date(dt1, "%d%b%y"))

> df
  dt1     x        dt2
1 22DEC16 10 2016-12-22
2 12JUN16 20 2016-06-12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark 2.2 or later:

```
library(magrittr)

df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(dt=c("22DEC16", "12JUN16")))

df %>% withColumn("parsed", to_date(.$dt,  "ddMMMyy")) %>% head()
```

```
       dt     parsed
1 22DEC16 2016-12-22
2 12JUN16 2016-06-12
```

Before Spark 2.2:

```
df %>%
  withColumn(
   "parsed",
   unix_timestamp(.$dt, "ddMMMyy") %>% cast("timestamp") %>% cast("date")) %>%
  head()
```

```
       dt     parsed
1 22DEC16 2016-12-22
2 12JUN16 2016-06-12
```

With this solution you should watch for possible timezone inconsistencies.