# Convert double to date using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

When a date is a string SparkR function `to_date` converts that to date format correctly, but when it is a double, it doesn't.

Also, the R package zoo works.

```
library(zoo)

df <- tibble::tibble(date = 17000.0)

as.Date(df$date)

# [1] "2016-07-18"
```

However, SparkR doesn't

```
df_spark <- as.DataFrame(df)
df_spark <- df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(date2 = to_date(df_spark$date, "MM/dd/yyyy"))

# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'unix_timestamp(`date`, 'MM/dd/yyyy')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, '`date`' is of double type.
```

I need the SparkR solution to convert double into a date.

Comment: does this probably help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620452/convert-double-to-date-using-spark-in-r

Comment: I used that and tried                                                                                         df <- tibble::tibble(date = 17000.0)
df$date <- as.character(df$date)

df_spark <- SparkR::as.DataFrame(df)

df_spark <- df_spark %>% SparkR::mutate(date2 = SparkR::to_date(df_spark$date, "MM/dd/yyyy"))                                                   but that rendered null.

Comment: try `magrittr` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716454/sparkr-cast-to-date-format
or `timestamp` https://forums.databricks.com/questions/7523/cast-function-in-sparkr-making-values-null-when-co.html
https://github.com/UrbanInstitute/sparkr-tutorials/blob/master/10_timeseries-1.md

Comment: Thanks! These examples are converting strings to dates, while I am trying to convert double to date. Can you use my example and provide code to convert double into date using SparkR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If value should be interpreted as the days since the beginning of the epoch you should use `date_add`:

```
df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(date2 = expr("date_add(to_date('1970-01-01'), date)")) %>% 
  head()
```

```
   date      date2                                                              
1 17000 2016-07-18
```

Basic arithmetics should work as well:

```
df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(
    date2 = to_date(cast(column("date") * 60 * 60 * 24, "timestamp"))) %>% 
  head()
```

```
   date      date2
1 17000 2016-07-18
```